# Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-server-2008-r2

I have been using Visual Studio 2012 on Winodws Server 2008 R2 sp1, Although apart from a bit slow performance it seem to work fine. But whenever I close the application, I get following error-

```
 Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 has stopped working
```

And prompts to restart or debug the program.

I read [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/et-EE/vssetup/thread/3b4d3051-c47f-4b84-8df5-a1f4feaf8916) that deleting following registry key, would fix the issue on 64 Bit machine.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
```

The issue is, I have not be able to locate the registry key beyond this path, on my machine.
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft`

Have you come across this situation earlier, what is the workaround for this.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: The key contains "Windows NT," not "WindowsNT." Perhaps that is your mistake.

Comment: Running as administrator got it working for me on Win7 x64

Comment: Try to re-install the software or download newer version (you'll get a latest feature update) and later on transfer your project files to the newer one. This might solve

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that other community members have the same error message as yours, and they are resolved the issue by deleting the following key in the Registry:

32-bit machine:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
 "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe"=""
```

64-bit machine:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
```

See this case for further information: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/d848776a-b00f-4311-ab09-3a8777462968
Thanks.

Comment: The issue is, I have not be able to locate the registry key beyond this path - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft,  on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the correct path goes like this:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
```