# When debuging the window doesn't appear

Tags: winforms, window

```
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace Server_chat
{
    class server
    {
        private static int myProt = 10000;
        private static byte[] buf2 = new byte[1024];
        private static Socket serverSocket;
        private static string message2;

        /// <summary>
        /// server socket
        /// </summary>
        public void Server_run()
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ip = ipHost.AddressList[0];

            serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ip,Program.form1.localport));
            serverSocket.Listen(10);
            Program.form1.myscan_box = "启动监听成功 ！！";

            Thread myThread = new Thread(ListenClientConnect);
            myThread.IsBackground = true;
            myThread.Start();
        }

        /// <summary>  
        /// 监听客户端连接  
        /// </summary>  
        private static void ListenClientConnect()
        {
            while (true)  // 点对点通信
            {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept();
                if (clientSocket.Connected == true)
                {
                    IPEndPoint client_endpoint = (IPEndPoint)clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint;
                    Program.form1.myclientip_box = client_endpoint.Address.ToString() + "\\" + client_endpoint.Port.ToString();
                    Program.form1.myscan_box = "连接客户端 " + client_endpoint.Address.ToString() + " 成功 !!";
                    //服务端接收线程
                    Thread receiveThread = new Thread(ReceiveMessage);
                    receiveThread.IsBackground = true;
                    receiveThread.Start(clientSocket);
                    //服务端发送线程
                    Thread sendThread = new Thread(SendMessage);
                    sendThread.IsBackground = true;
                    sendThread.Start(clientSocket);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>  
        /// receive message 
        /// </summary>  
        /// <param name="clientSocket"></param>  
        private static void ReceiveMessage(object clientSocket)
        {
            Socket myClientSocket = (Socket)clientSocket;
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    int len = myClientSocket.Receive(buf2);
                    message2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf2).Substring(0, len);
                    IPEndPoint client_endpoint = (IPEndPoint)myClientSocket.RemoteEndPoint;
                    Program.form1.myscan_box = client_endpoint.Address +": "+ message2;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Program.form1.myscan_box = ex.Message;
                    myClientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    myClientSocket.Close();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// send message
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clientSocket"></param>
        private static void SendMessage(object clientSocket)
        {
            Socket myClientSocket = (Socket)clientSocket;
            while (true)
            {
                if (Program.form1.send_flag11 == 1)
                {
                    myClientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Program.form1.message11));
                    Program.form1.send_flag11 = 0;
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

`When starting or debugging my program the window doesn't appear. But vs2012 suggests the debug session is ready.

When startting the program, the window appears but a popup window with the message "the program has stopped working, choose to debug or stop".

What's the problem? What should I do?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace Server_chat
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string localip;
        public int localport = 10002;
        public string s_sendMessage;
        public static int send_flag = 0;


        public string message11
        {
            get { return s_sendMessage; }
        }
        public int send_flag11
        {
            get { return send_flag; }
            set { send_flag = value; }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
            localip = ipAddr.ToString();

            myip_box.Text = localip;
            port_box.Text = localport.ToString();


            server myserver = new server();
            Thread th_server = new Thread(myserver.Server_run);
            th_server.IsBackground = true;
            th_server.Start();
        }

        private void setting_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            localport = Int16.Parse(port_box.Text);
            scan_box.AppendText("\r\n" + "端口改成： " + port_box.Text);
        }

        private void send_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            s_sendMessage = chat_box.Text;
            chat_box.Text = "";
            scan_box.AppendText(s_sendMessage + "\r\n");
            send_flag = 1;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022518/microsoft-visual-studio-2012-has-stopped-working might help

Comment: `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;` - it is not too wise to use this. Are you sure you really know what it does, or did you do that just to "remove CrossthreadExceptions"? If the second, then switch to using control.Invoke instead. Turning off the check-for option with a more complicated program and a bit of bad luck might even crash your application silently, but I dont think it is the case here.

Comment: Also, you will probbaly need to show us the 'server' class too. BTW. I noticed that your code has hardcoded port number. Maybe it is just that this port is already in use and you forgot to handle exceptions thrown from tcpserver class?

Comment: but when I change the port ,debuge again,it still doesn't appear the main window.

Comment: Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;   I used it before,it succeeded for serveral  times

Comment: sorry,I didn't notice ,I uploaded the "server.cs" just now