# Why I am getting error "Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 has stopped working" (when i click on textbox)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, shutdown

I am developing winforms application in C#. I have two different development computers having Windows 7 and VS2012.

I created one windows app with a form and controls on first computer & it is working fine.
When i transfer code to second computer and select any text box(by clicking on it),I am getting error popup `Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 has stopped working`

If i create a new form on second computer with control,then there is no issue.Issue is only with the textboxes and comboboxes created on first computer.I installed and reinstalled my VS also but no luck.

Note: I read these posts but these are different senarios. [RELATED Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022518/microsoft-visual-studio-2012-has-stopped-working)

Here is alert that i am getting

[image: ERROR]

Have you come across this situation earlier, what is the workaround for this.

Thank you for your help !

**UPDATED1:**
This is only with text fields and combo boxes not with buttons etc

Comment: There's a whole slew of possible causes, and it's hard to determine what the cause could be.
Is the first or second machine using some odd language setting?
Also, can we see some of the possibly offending code?

Comment: There is no odd language setting, and there is no code involve,I just double click my form in solution explorer and click on textbox..i got this alert

Comment: The form is still generated with code.
The editor just builds the initialisation code for the form.
I'm guessing the text box has some kind of property value that causes this.

Comment: @TimothyGroote: My Form Name is Accounts.cs..Do you want me to show code of Accounts.Designer.cs OR  .resx file?

Comment: The Designer.cs file should be of help, i think.

Comment: @TimothyGroote: I updated my question with code showing,please have a look.

Comment: Coming from Meta--this question is actually not the worst, quality wise. You explained what you did and what the problem is. However, I think you have been downvoted because it's almost impossible for someone to help you without seeing your code and your environment. As indicated by the answers, all anyone can do is tell you how to debug yourself. SO is better suited to questions which can be definitively answered. If you find the solution to your problem, your answer could help to make this question more useful for the community, though. :)

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio emits a shed load of debugging information, which can be viewed with Microsoft's application called DbgView. Below are the instructions on how to modify VisualStudio .config file, how to enable logging and where to get DbgView.

(1) This is for a general guidance, which will give you idea, but you need to apply changes as in the link #2:
[VS2010 always thinks project is out of date but nothing has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762930/vs2010-always-thinks-project-is-out-of-date-but-nothing-has-changed)

(2) This is the actual change to config file instead of one in the link above:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewarnottms/archive/2012/06/07/enable-c-and-javascript-project-system-tracing.aspx

(3) You may need to enable Verbose logging mode:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewarnottms/archive/2012/06/07/enable-c-and-javascript-project-system-tracing.aspx#10397394

(4) To view log you’ll need to run this tool before reproducing the issue:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is start a second Visual Studio and attach it as a debugger to the devenv.exe process of the first. Then do whatever you do to get the first VS to crash. The debugger should catch the exception and break (otherwise you may have to setup the debugger to break on all exceptions via the Debug > Exceptions menu)

Pretty often the stacktrace and other information provided by the automatic breakpoint will give you a decent indication of what's going on (for instance if it's a plugin that is going haywire) or at the very least another error message you can ask Google about.